# Postman Test | I want to save id in variable but i need to split that id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman, postman-testcase

I am getting the following id in response "id": "FsuJ6ld97vVC2mkh5bGo5K-us|0000001". I always need to take value before | and ignore the rest of values after us. also value is not consistent, sometimes it's 24 values and sometimes 23. I have used sub String function but that is not very helpful.
Let me know how can i do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` to do that.

```
let id = "FsuJ6ld97vVC2mkh5bGo5K-us|0000001";
id = id.split("|")[0];
//FsuJ6ld97vVC2mkh5bGo5K-us
```